# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 50

Tags: c#

I have no idea what it means, can I get some help please

> "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 50."

**Code:**

```
InitializeComponent();
connString = "Data   Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\andrew\\Documents\\Vinyl0.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
query = "SELECT * FROM Record";
dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connString); //This is where the error appears.
dTable = new DataTable();
cBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dAdapter);
cBuilder.QuotePrefix = "[";
cBuilder.QuoteSuffix = "]";
myDataView = dTable.DefaultView;
dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
BindingSource bndSource = new BindingSource();
bndSource.DataSource = dTable;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
C:\\Users\andrew
```

`\a` is the escape sequence for the "alert" character (U+0007)... I suspect you wanted a backslash followed by "a". You were unlucky that you didn't just get a compile-time error, which you'd have done if you'd had `\j` or some other invalid escape sequence.

I would suggest using a verbatim string literal instead, so that you don't need to double all the backslashes:

```
connString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\andrew\Documents\Vinyl0.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm noticing a `C:\\Users\andrew\\`.

It looks like you were going for a `\\` in the middle but ended up with `\a` instead, which is an escape sequence for a character that ruins the format of your connection string.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a back slash in front of the `a` of "andrew". It should look like this:

```
connString = "Data   Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\andrew\\Documents\\Vinyl0.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

Answer (score 2):

`C:\\Users\`  is your problem, you need to change it to `C:\\Users\\`